# sqlite3 bash grep username

Tags: bash, sqlite

```
#!/bin/bash
username=$(sqlite3 db.sl3 "select user from main";)
yad --list --column="#" "$username" --height 200
```

I want to display the usernames of my db in a list and then select one of theme.
The problem with the code above is that the username "a b c" are treated as an unique username.
How can i split them into more username?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your user names don't contain any spaces or special characters (`*?\[`), you need just remove `"` and it will work ok:

```
yad --list --column="#" $username --height 200
```

Comment: Excepting for usernames which contain spaces.

Answer (score 4):

In such cases is advisable to store the data in an array. With version 4.0 or never the simplest is to use `mapfile` to populate it:

```
#!/bin/bash
mapfile username < <(sqlite3 db.sl3 "select user from main")
yad --list --column="#" "${username[@]}" --height 200
```

Comment: I must read the newest bash v4 function :) thanks!!